# Fill with values from an earlier time point - Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to `generate` a variable that is filled using a sequence of values starting at `time==1`.

The sequence changes everytime the `variable` `rest1w` changes from 0 to 1 or vice versa.

Firstly, I think I need to generate `x`, that is where the sequence restarts (see below example dataset). In my example, this is uniform, but in my full dataset the change varies (i.e. it does not change at every 5th observation).

```
 list time restload trainload rest1w x in 1/15

         +-----------------------------------------+
         | time   restload   trainload   rest1w   x |
         |-----------------------------------------|
      1. |    1   .1994715   .4780615        0   1 |
      2. |    2   .2077734    .471063        0   2 |
      3. |    3   .2157595   .4641159        0   3 |
      4. |    4   .2234298   .4572202        0   4 |
      5. |    5   .2307843   .4503757        0   5 |
         |-----------------------------------------|
      6. |    6   .2378229   .4435827        1   1 |
      7. |    7   .2445457    .436841        1   2 |
      8. |    8   .2509527   .4301506        1   3 |
      9. |    9   .2570438   .4235116        1   4 |
     10. |   10   .2628191   .4169239        1   5 |
         |-----------------------------------------|
     11. |   11   .2682785   .4103876        0   1 |
     12. |   12   .2734221   .4039026        0   2 |
     13. |   13   .2782499    .397469        0   3 |
     14. |   14   .2827618   .3910867        0   4 |
     15. |   15   .2869579   .3847558        0   5 |
         +-----------------------------------------+
```

Secondly, I need to `generate` a variable `load`. Which as per below shows how I would like to restart from `time==1` everytime the sequence restarts. That is, at the second sequence where `rest1w==0`, `load!=trainload`.

The rule is that for each new sequence of 0's the value for `load` again goes back to the start of time (where `time==1`). This is demonstrated by the `load` values in the second sequence of 0's being exactly the same as the first sequence. In other words, where `time==1`, `trainload==.478` then `load==.478`; BUT where `time==11`, then `load==.478` (the clock essentially restarts for `load` so `time==1`) and in sequence where `time==15`, `load==.450` (the same `load` as for where `time==5`). This is why I wanted to generate `x`, as I think I could just use that as my new `time` variable.

```
         +-----------------------------------------+
         | time   restload   trainload   rest1w   x  load
         |-----------------------------------------
      1. |    1   .1994715   .4780615        0   1   .4780615
      2. |    2   .2077734    .471063        0   2   .471063
      3. |    3   .2157595   .4641159        0   3   .4641159
      4. |    4   .2234298   .4572202        0   4   .4572202
      5. |    5   .2307843   .4503757        0   5   .4503757
         |-----------------------------------------
      6. |    6   .2378229   .4435827        1   1   .1994715
      7. |    7   .2445457    .436841        1   2   .2077734
      8. |    8   .2509527   .4301506        1   3   .2157595
      9. |    9   .2570438   .4235116        1   4   .2234298
     10. |   10   .2628191   .4169239        1   5   .2307843
         |-----------------------------------------
     11. |   11   .2682785   .4103876        0   1   .4780615 
     12. |   12   .2734221   .4039026        0   2   .471063
     13. |   13   .2782499    .397469        0   3   .4641159
     14. |   14   .2827618   .3910867        0   4   .4572202
     15. |   15   .2869579   .3847558        0   5   .4503757
         +-----------------------------------------+
```

The below code only gives me an entry for where `_n==1`:

```
gen load==.
replace load = restload[_n==1] if rest1w==1
```

And I like the use of `levelsof` but haven't been able to get it to work (although it might work once I have generated `x`, but when using time it doesn't restart the sequence obviously).

```
gen load=.
levelsof x, local(levels) 
 foreach l of local levels {
     replace load=trainload if rest1w==0
     replace load=restload if rest1w==1  
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your statement of the problem is unclear.  While presenting code is expected in Stack Overflow, another expectation is a clear statement of, in this case, the rules you are trying to implement in the code. The only rule I think I understand is "if the first sequence has rest1w==0 then load=trainload for that sequence." But even that rule only applies to the first sequence; it doesn't apply to the third sequence, which again has rest1w==0.

Comment: Apologies for not being able to explain in writing so well, I hoped the example data for the variables I want to generate (`x` and `load`) might help. I have added what I think you mean by the rule. It is easy just for the first sequence as obviously the code would just be `gen load=trainload if rest1w==0`, but because the time clock resets in the subsequent sequences (i.e. the 2nd sequence) this complicates things.

Comment: That helps me along, although it does not explain what would happen if any of the subsequent sequences were longer than the first sequence.

Comment: The sequences do differ, with some longer than others, but that should not matter because trainload and restload are essentially not related to the other values in the dataset (trainload keeps decreasing and restload keeps increasing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up cross-posting this on statalist.org and got two workable answers.

http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1355917-fill-with-values-from-an-earlier-time-point

These were:

```
gen newtime = 1 if rest1w[_n - 1] != rest1w
replace newtime = newtime[_n - 1] + 1 if newtime == .
gen newload = cond(rest1w == 0, trainload[newtime], restload[newtime])
```

and...

```
gen newtime = 1 
replace newtime = newtime[_n-1] + 1 if rest1w == rest1w[_n-1]
gen newload = .
replace newload = restload[newtime] if rest1w == 1
replace newload = trainload[newtime] if rest1w == 0
```